# Google Ad not visible when using custom ad size with PublisherAdView

Tags: android, admob, google-dfp, adview

When using PublisherAdView with size: `AdSize.BANNER`. The ad I wanna display works pretty fine, but when setting a custom size, the operation does not succeed. In fact the ad is being loaded but not displayed, I go successfully in the callback`onAdLoaded`:

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            Log.d(TAG, "Ad loaded");
        }
});
```

I simply set my custom size like this:

```
AdSize[] adSizes = {new AdSize(88, 31), AdSize.BANNER};
mAdView = new PublisherAdView(getActivity());
mAdContainer.addView(mAdView);
mAdView.setAdUnitId(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
mAdView.setAdSizes(adSizes);
```

No rocket-science here but I'm doubting it is possible to use a custom size. Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can use any size you want (as long as it fits), my client provides small ad sizes and we manage to make it work. "As long as it fits" means for example, when you write something like:

```
AdSize[] adSizes = {new AdSize(89, 31), AdSize.SMART_BANNER};
```

And your provided ad size is 88X31, that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't use any size you want. According to the [docs here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize), you can use the following:

```
AdSize BANNER => 320x50 density-independent pixels

AdSize FULL_BANNER => 468x60 density-independent pixels

AdSize LARGE_BANNER => 320x100 density-independent pixels

AdSize LEADERBOARD => 728x90 density-independent pixels

AdSize MEDIUM_RECTANGLE => 300x250 density-independent pixels

AdSize SMART_BANNER => A dynamically sized banner that is full-width and auto-height

AdSize WIDE_SKYSCRAPER => 160x600 density-independent pixels. This size is currently not supported by the Google Mobile Ads network; this is intended for mediation ad networks only.
```

Comment: This link to the documentation should be this one https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize

Comment: @Sniper Thanks. Updated!